# Spark Streaming Not reading all Kafka Records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are sending 15 records from kafka to SparkStreaming, but spark is receiving only 11 records. I am using spark 2.1.0 and kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0.

CODE

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class KafkaToSparkData {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int timeDuration = 100;
    int consumerNumberOfThreads = 1;
    String consumerTopic = "InputDataTopic";
    String zookeeperUrl = "localhost:2181";
    String consumerTopicGroup =  "testgroup";
    String producerKafkaUrl = "localhost:9092";
    String producerTopic =  "OutputDataTopic";
    String sparkMasterUrl = "local[2]";

    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicMap.put(consumerTopic, consumerNumberOfThreads);

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master(sparkMasterUrl).appName("Kafka-Spark").getOrCreate();

    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());

    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(javaSparkContext, new Duration(timeDuration));

    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(javaStreamingContext, zookeeperUrl, consumerTopicGroup, topicMap);

    JavaDStream<String> NewRecord = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public String call(Tuple2<String, String> line) throws Exception {

            String responseToKafka = "";
            System.out.println(" Data IS " + line);

            String ValueData = line._2;
            responseToKafka = ValueData + "|" + "0";

            Properties configProperties = new Properties();
            configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, producerKafkaUrl);
            configProperties.put("key.serializer", org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class);
            configProperties.put("value.serializer", org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class);

            KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(configProperties);

            ProducerRecord<String, String> topicMessage = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(producerTopic,responseToKafka);
            producer.send(topicMessage);
            producer.close();

            return responseToKafka;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(" Printing Record" );
    NewRecord.print();

    javaStreamingContext.start();
    javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();
    javaStreamingContext.close();

    }
}
```

Kafka Producer

bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic InputDataTopic
#
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18

Kafka Consumer

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic OutputDataTopic --from-beginning
#
1|0
2|0
3|0
4|0
5|0
6|0
7|0
8|0
9|0
10|0
11|0

Could somebody help me on this?

Comment: could you add a complete reproducible example? ie. add also the producer.

Comment: @maasg, I have added complete code. I am sending 18 records from kafka producer.. but kafka-consumer is receiving only 11 processed records

Comment: Hi, Could somebody please help me on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we see here is an effect of how lazy operations work in Spark.
Here, we are using a `map` operation to cause a side-effect, namely, to send some data to Kafka.

The stream is then materialized using `print`. By default, `print` will show the first 10 elements of the stream, but takes `n+1` elements in order to show a "..." to indicate when there are more.

This `take(11)` forces the materialization of the first 11 elements, so they are taken from the original stream and processed with the `map` function. This results in a partial publishing to Kafka.

How to solve this? Well, the hint is already above: *DO NOT USE* side-effects in a `map` function. 
In this case, the correct output operation to consume the stream and send it to Kafka should be `foreachRDD`.

Furthermore, to avoid creating a Kafka producer instance for each element, we process the internal `RDD` using `foreachPartition`.

A code skeleton of this process looks like this:

```
messages.foreachRDD{rdd => 
  rdd.foreachPartition{partitionIter => 
       producer = // create producer
       partitionIter.foreach{elem =>
           record = createRecord(elem)
           producer.send(record)
       }
       producer.flush()  
       producer.close()
   }
}
```

Comment: Came here to post my solution(i.e After changing NewRecord.print(); to NewRecord.print(20); found that issue is with print() method. So changed code to NewRecord.count().print();) but now found good explanation and best approach/solution from you. Thank you for the response. Now I will follow your solution( i.e foreachRDD).